# installing JDK 8 on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: jdk

Hello everyone I have JDK 8 installation file but I don,t know how to install it offline.
could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the installation file in .rpm format(that oracle jdk ships with)

```
sudo apt-get install alien
alien <filename>.rpm
dpkg -i <filename>.deb
```

Note - Alien is the a package that converts rpm to deb

<s>Or what I would actually suggest you to do is</s>

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

And follow the onscreen instructions. 'Strikingly simple' of-course

Sorry, you asked for offline instructions

Comment: I,m sorry but I forgot to say that I have been downloaded a folder which contains JDK 8 installation not a single file